# All In One WP Migration - Ampps - Mac - Can't import

Tags: wordpress

I've come across this issue quite a few times with the All In One Migration tool.

The error I get is:

> Unable to import Your PHP is 32-bit. In order to import your file,
>   please change your PHP version to 64-bit and try again. Technical
>   details

So, I'm using Ampps on a MacBook Pro, and I don't see a solution to import this file other than using another plugin like Duplicator Pro.

Not sure if any of you have come across this error but does anyone know of a way to restore this file?

Quite interested in finding a solution since I find the All In One Migration plugin to be the best plugin available in terms of website transfers... especially when this file was 32GB :/ crazy I know but I've just taken over this website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that my localhost cannot handle files larger than 2GB.

A possible solution is to use https://localwp.com/ for WordPress localhost.

Either that or run some optimisation, especially with compressing images to get the website under 2GB to be able to import it into localhost if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a PHP script that breaks the import into chunks. https://github.com/fadlee/bigdump

Ive used this on WordPress sites a few times.

[wpcli](https://wp-cli.org/) is also something to look into, they have some command lines for migration.